# How do I set up my first view with Draggable Views module?

Tags: drupal-6, drupal-views, drupal-modules

I'm learning how to use Draggable Views for Drupal 6 for the first time, following this tutorial: http://thedesignspace.net/MT2archives/000666.html . I'm encountering a problem though: in part 4, once I set up the draggable table ( http://thedesignspace.net/MT2archives/000708.html ) the entire preview disappears, showing no table. Switching the style to another type, such as table, brings everything back. Directly viewing the page from its path makes no difference. Any ideas of what the problem could be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not all of my modules were up to date when I encountered this problem. My mistake. Always update all modules first upon being stumped by incompatibility errors, even if the modules in question do not seem to have anything to do with the error.